# ¿Cómo se decodifica correctamente en java un String que contiene el base64 de un archivo ya sea de imagen o un documento pdf?

Tags: java, spring, base64

estoy desarrollando un api que recibe en el request en un String un base64, ya sea de una imagen (jpg, jpeg, etc) o un documento pdf, mi api deberia decodificar los base64 para interpretar el archivo y almacenarlos en rutas temporales, para luego esas rutas anexarlas a un arreglo de string de tipo String[] = {} y pasarlo por parametro a un servicio de envio de correos que para adjuntar archivos, los recibe en ese arreglo de string. con la logica que tengo alli adjunta la imagen bien, pero el pdf pareciera que no lo procesa, en vez de anexar al corre el pdf, anexa un archivo sin formato ni extension. el bloque donde estoy haciendolo es:

```
ArrayList<String> filesArray = rq.getFileArray();
            ArrayList<String> arrayFilePaths = new ArrayList<>(); // Utilizaremos una lista para almacenar las rutas de los archivos temporales

            for (String file : filesArray) {
                byte[] decodedFile = Base64.getDecoder().decode(file);
                String extension = ""; // Initialize the extension variable

                // Get the content type of the file
                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedFile);
                String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(bis);

                // Extract the file extension from the content type
                if (contentType != null) {
                    if (contentType.equals("application/pdf")) {
                        extension = ".pdf";
                    } else {
                        String[] parts = contentType.split("/");
                        if (parts.length > 1) {
                            extension = "." + parts[1];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    extension = ".pdf";
                }

                // Create a temporary file with the extension
                File tempFile;
                try {
                    tempFile = File.createTempFile("file", extension);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                    fos.write(decodedFile);
                    fos.close();
                    arrayFilePaths.add(tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
ServicioMicrosoft servicioMicrosoft = new ServicioMicrosoft(apiEmailOffice);
                    String[] arrayEmail = {"liruiz@bancomercantil.com"};
                    String html = emailTempDataModific;
                    Resource resourceHtml = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:template/actDatosEmail.html");
                    InputStream inputStream = resourceHtml.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);
                    String htmlContent = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    String htmlParm = htmlContent.replace("${id}", String.valueOf(id));
                    htmlParm = htmlParm.replace("${nombre}", String.valueOf(name));
                    htmlParm = htmlParm.replace("${cedula}", String.valueOf(cedula));
                    logger.info("<<<< HTML PROCESADO >>>> " + htmlParm);
                    
                    boolean respuestaPlantilla = servicioMicrosoft.sendEmailPlantillaHtml("asunto", htmlParm, arrayEmail, arrayFilePaths.toArray(new String[0])); // Pasar la lista de rutas como un array de String
                    logger.info("respuestaPlantilla " + respuestaPlantilla);
                    
                    for (String path : arrayFilePaths) {
                        logger.info(" >>>> PATH TEMP >>> " + path);
                    }

                    data = new ResponseRS(rq.get_infoMsg(), 0, ">>> correo enviado. . .");
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usas Base64 para recibir un fichero? ¿Por qué no enviarlo como bytes en el cuerpo de la request? Base64 hace que necesites un 33% más de datos para enviar cualquier cosa

Comment: por lo que entendi asi lo mandara el front, no fue decision mia, tengo que adecuar en base a esa situación

Comment: ¿Qué dice la documentación sobre `sendEmailPlantillaHtml`? Tal vez lo estés usando mal.

Comment: @Mateo la documentación: boolean respuestaPlantilla=servicioMicrosoft.sendEmailPlantillaHtml("asunto", html, arrayEmail, arrayFile); donde el arrayFile es String[] arrayFile= {}; un arreglo de strings donde se le pasan las rutas temporales de los archivos para adjuntarlos al email